# How to find out the Big Oh complexity in a function

Tags: algorithm

How do I determine the order between these two functions: `n^(2.5)` & `100n^(2/3)`
Additionally, for `log(n!)`.

Comment: pick really big numbers?

Comment: is this rigorous proof-based math homework, or something less precise? @qwertymk's suggestion is probably good for the second, but not the first

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+log%28x%21%29+and+y%3Dx%5E2.5+and+y%3Dx%5E.6667%2C+x%3D0+to+10) may help.  Assuming that what you're actually trying to do is order these functions from least complex to most complex.

Answer (score 4):

**[Edit]** Big-O is used for comparing algorithms, and is used to describe the limiting behavior of a function.

So, if you are given 3 algorithms with complexity `O(n^2.5), O(n^(2/3)) and O(log n!)`, to compare these, you see how they will behave for very large values of `n`. In this case, `n^2.5` is greater than `n^(2/3)`. So, `O(n^(2/3))` is better than `O(n^2.5)` algorithm.
 For third one, we know that n! < n^n [1*2*..*n < n*n*..*n], so `logn! < nlogn`. For very large values of `n`, `logn!` will get closer to `nlogn`, so it can be inferred that `logn! > n^2/3`.

So, the final order will be `O(n^2/3) < O(logn!) < O(n^2.5)`.

PS: All comparisons are made for very large values of n.

Comment: Big-O is *for functions* ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation ). And can be used for algorithms.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: ah, yes! I meant to say that functions don't have big-o _complexity_. Thanks.

Comment: So if given 4n^2, log3(n), 20n, n^2.5, log(n!), n^n, 3^n, n log (n), 100n^(2/3), 2^n, 2^(n+1), n!, (n-1)!, 2^2n

The order (increasing order of their big O complexity) would be 
log3(n) < 20n < n logn < 4n^2 < 100n^(2/3) < log(n!) < n^(2.5) < 2^n < 2^(n+1) < 3^n < 2^(2n) < (n-1)! < n^n < n!

? Is that right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806039/arrange-in-increasing-order-of-their-big-oh-complexity for the answer.

Comment: @Rachel: You should be able to figure out this answer by yourself. Also, don't be fooled by constants, for very large values of n, they disappear in comparisons. In my post I have clearly shown that n! < n^n, still you have made a mistake there. See Franck's answer for correct order.

Answer (score 3):

Functions don't have big-O complexity.  Big-O complexity measures are for *algorithms* that implement functions.

To illustrate, each one of those functions could (in theory) be implemented as a giant lookup table, and that would give `O(1)` performance.  Not exactly practical ... but that's not the point.

<sub>Note for people who don't "get it".  You *can* use big-O notation to characterize a function, but *that is not a measure of the complexity of the function*.  It is simply a way of saying something about how the function behaves for large (enough) parameters.  Complexity is about characterizing computational processes, and functions are agnostic of how they are computed.  Indeed, they don't even need to be computable.</sub>

---

On the other hand, if those functions are functions of performance depending on some parameter `n`, and you are asking how turn them into big-O complexity measures ...

The best answer is to *Do The Math*.   Take the formal definition of big-O complexity (which can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)), plug in your function `f` and solve for `g`.

If your mathematical skills are not up to that, then another alternative is to get some graph paper and a calculator, and plot how those functions grow as `n` gets very large.  But you need to be careful that you are looking at the *rate of growth* (not the absolute values) and that you consider values of `n` that are large enough.

Comment: Big-O is *for functions* ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation ). And can be used for algorithms.

Comment: You can't measure the complexity of a function.  That's the point I'm trying to make.  You can take the big-O of a function, but it doesn't measure the complexity of the function.  It just measures the limiting behavior of the function's range.

Comment: I'm saying there is.  The terminology is broken.  If I was marking an exam, and some student wrote that in their answer, they would lose marks for abusing the terminology.  And since Rachel is a student, it is important to point this out to her and others reading her questions.  Now **you** may think that correct use of terminology is unimportant, but her examiners won't agree.

Comment: O() is defined for *functions* and its purest form has nothing to do with *algorithms* (see the definition...). I agree that the word *complexity* is not used in the function context, but your answer gives the misleading idea that there's no Big-O for functions.

Comment: You have to misread "don't have big-O complexity" as "cannot be characterized by big-O notation" in order to be mislead.

Comment: They need to learn to be ... if they are going to get good marks.