# Arrange in increasing order of their Big Oh Complexity

Tags: algorithm

So if given

4n^2, log3(n), 20n, n^2.5, log(n!), n^n, 3^n, n log (n), 100n^(2/3), 2^n, 2^(n+1), n!, (n-1)!, 2^2n

The order (increasing order of their big O complexity) would be

log3(n) < 20n < n logn < 4n^2 < 100n^(2/3) < log(n!) < n^(2.5) < 2^n < 2^(n+1) < 3^n < 2^(2n) < (n-1)! < n^n < n!

this is when n is a large number. Is that right?

Comment: yes it is when n is large; there should be a CLRS tag for questions ;)

Comment: I don't think 4n^2 is less than 100n^(2/3) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%284n%5E2%2C+100n%5E%282%2F3%29%29

Comment: And n^n is always bigger than n!, as n^n = (n*n*n*n*n....) n times, but n! = (1*2*3*4...n) n times

Answer (score 7):

To sum up, as n tends to +infinite, in terms of big Oh complexity:

log3(n) < 100n^(2/3) < 20n < log(n!) < n log(n) < 4n^2 < n^(2.5) < 2^n ~ 2^(n+1) < 3^n < 2^(2n) < (n-1)! < n! < n^n

This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) may interest you.

EDIT: regarding n! vs. n^n

Using Stirling's approximation, we have:
[image]
therefore O(n!) ~O(sqrt(n) * n^n * e^(-n))
hence O(sqrt(n)) ~ O(e^(-n))  iff O(n^n) ~ O(n!).
But O(sqrt(n)) ~ O(e^(-n)) is false.
Therefore O(n^n) ~ O(n!) is false.
Since n! < n^n, we have n! = o(n^n). QED.

Here is another proof from [djfm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088499/djfm) which does not rely on Stirling's approximation:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the ~ -sign? 
The `2^n ~ 2^(n-1)` made me believe that you mean that the complexities are equal (i.e. `O(2^n) = O(2^(n+1))`)

However, `O(n!)` and `O(n^n)` are not equal.

Comment: Oops sorry, you're right. Thanks! I got fooled by WP (which says that n log(n) ~ log(n!)), was suspicious but forgot to edit my answer after checking. Answer corrected.